# error "ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1" when converting to standalone qgis script

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to convert a python script for qgis (2.18.2 Las Palmas) to executable (.exe) using pyinstaller

This is a very simple example (I'm just a beginner):

```
from qgis.core import *
import os
print "prova"
```

this is the coomand I use to convert esempio.py to esempio.exe:

```
pyinstaller esempio.py --onefile
```

when I run esempio.exe the following message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esempio.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.4-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "c:\progra~1\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.4-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 28, in <module>
ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1
[10208] Failed to execute script esempio
```

Can someone help me